# How to test actions which are performed in callback using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-services

I have two controllers and a service. In the first controller I have subscribed to an event to do some stuff. The second controller preforms some actions and when it is done, broadcasts the event. Please see the example below, the timeout is just for emulation of long running actions. I would like to test that *hasLoaded* is set to true using Jasmine 2.0 Please advise.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.hasLoaded = false;
    $scope.fileName = '';
    
    myService.onLoaded($scope, function(e, data){
         // I want to test the following two lines, in the really the code here is much more complex
        $scope.fileName = data.fileName;
        $scope.hasLoaded = true;
    });
}]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', 'myService', function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, myService) {
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    $scope.title = 'Click me to load';

    $scope.load = function(){
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        $scope.title = 'Loading, please wait...';
        
        $timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.$emit('loaded', { fileName: 'test.txt'});
        }, 1000);
    };

    myService.onLoaded($scope, function(){
        $scope.hasLoaded = true;
    });
}]);

myApp.service('myService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    this.onLoaded = function(scope, callback) {
        var handler = $rootScope.$on('loaded', callback);
        scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
        <div ng-show="hasLoaded">{{fileName}} loaded !!!</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
        <button ng-click="load()" ng-hide="hasLoaded" ng-disabled="isLoading" ng-bind="title"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: I have added parameter into the broadcast call to make it more closer to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be testing each of your pieces (controllers and services) separately. In your case, the tests for the controller that sets the hasLoaded properly really just needs to test that your register with the service correctly and that the callback does what you expect:

```
    it("should register with the service and do the right thing when the callback is executed", inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, myService) {
        var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        spyOn(myService, 'onLoaded').and.callThrough();

        var ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl1', {$scope: $scope, myService: myService});
        $scope.$apply();

        //verify that the controller registers its scope with the service
        expect(myService.onLoaded).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope, jasmine.any(Function));
        //now call the callback that was registered to see if it sets the property correctly

        var mockData = {
            fileName: 'some file name'
        };
        myService.onLoaded.calls.argsFor(0)[1]('loaded', mockData);
        expect($scope.hasLoaded).toBeTruthy();
        expect($scope.fileName).toBe("some file name");
    }));
```

Then write tests for your service and other controller separately.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need. Can you please tell me why do we need to have $scope.$apply(); call?

Comment: You actually don't in your case. I'm just used to doing it because lately I've been testing with mock promises that require $apply() in order to be resolved in the test.